# Where is apache-cassandra-x.x.x.jar in lib?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, cassandra

I was reading somewhere that in order to use the `org.apache.cassandra` classes in my java project I need to import the `apache-cassandra-x.x.x.jar` in my java project CLASSPATH but I was unable to find it in any of the folders in my `/cassandra` path. Has it been deprecated? Is there an alternative to it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really had to say it. apache-cassandra-x.x.x.jar sounds like an adult film title.

Comment: I am glad to hear that people are deriving pleasure from the simplistic vagaries of prose :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have `apache-cassandra-0.6.9.jar` in my cassandra's `lib` directory, and that was unpacked as-is from the `.tgz` distro.

Are you sure you downloaded the `bin` distro, rather than the `src`?

Comment: yeah..I think that's what happened. I downloaded the src instead of the bin distro.

Comment: fixed. Doing an "ant jar" from the command line fixed it by putting the JAR in the build folder. Thanks for the help.